# Password unlock and access to widgets?

Tags: lock-screens, 4.2-jelly-bean, app-widgets, password, samsung-galaxy-s-4

So I just realised that having a Swipe unlock allows you to have widgets and access to the camera etc. But whenever I put a password, these features are gone.

Is there a way I can allow for a swipe feature along with widgets etc, but then ask for a password ??

For example: A password lock app that I can safely use instead of the phone's password lock, then use the phone's swipe to unlock feature and have the password app prompt before action continues ?

Answer (score 1):

```
 Lock screen is probably the most discussed topic since release of jellybeans.
```

Well currently there is only one solution to yours problem if device is not rooted. install another lock screen which will provide you that slider shortcuts and which will then be followed by stock lock screen with pin/password. one software is widget locker available in market. however this will be a waste of memory using dual lock screens.

```
 Alternatively I'm looking for a solution for a rooted device. I will post once found.
```

Most custom roms comes with this feature as stock like AOKP and MIUI.

Comment: Is there a phone lock app that is safe to use and can replace the phone's password lock ? So I can use swipe, but then it asks for password before continuing ?

Comment: widget locker available in market.. enjoy...